# If $f$ convex, then $f(x)=\sup_{(a,b)\in E}(ax+b)$ where $E=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb Q^2\mid \forall x, f(x)\geq ax+b\}$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ a convex function. I would like to prove that $$f(x)=\sup_{(a,b)\in E}(ax+b),$$ where $$E=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb Q^2\mid \forall x, f(x)\geq ax+b\}.$$

Let $f'_r$ and $f'_l$ the derivative at left and at right. Let $a\in\mathbb R$. Since $$f(x)\geq \min\{f'_r(a),f'_l(a)\}(x-a)+f(a),$$

for all $x\in\mathbb R$, we get that $E\neq \emptyset$ and upper bounded. So the supremum is well defined. By definition, $f(x)\geq \sup_{(a,b)\in E}(ax+b)$. But how can I prove the converse inequality ? I mean, how can I get $$f(x)\leq \sup_{(a,b)\in\mathbb Q^2}(ax+b) \ \ ?$$
Any idea ?

Comment: Since $f$ is convex, there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(z) \geq az + b$ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$ and such that $f(x) = ax + b$. Now take $((a_n,b_n))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as a sequence of rational approximates of $(a,b)$ and appeal to a convergence argument.